# BULKINSERT from MatLab to SQL server

Tags: bulkinsert

I'm running a MatLab script, where I update a table on a SQL connection. All is OK if I read or update table from SQL server trhough matLab simple command; data appears perfectly. But I'm facing troubles when I use BULINSERT command. No data are updated!! However, it works while SQL console of SQL Server Management Studio.

My code (MatLab sample):

```
conn = database('Dados_SQL','sa','SQL@Edison');
A = {100000.00,'KGreen','06/22/2011','Challengers'};
A = A(ones(10000,1),:);
fid = fopen('c:\temp\tmp.txt','wt'); 
for i = 1:size(A,1)
fprintf(fid,'%10.2f \t %s \t %s \t %s \n',A{i,1}, ...
A{i,2},A{i,3},A{i,4});
e = exec(conn,['bulk insert BULKTEST from '...
'''c:\temp\tmp.txt''with (fieldterminator = ''\t'', '...
'rowterminator = ''\n'')']);
end

close(e);
```

Thanks in advance.!
Edison.

Comment: did you check for errors? you're just firing off the query call and quitting.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL has problems reading from a drive which is not local to the database. If your C drive is not the database drive, that might be the problem. You have two options:

1. Generate a file that you save onto the database server from matlab. Perhaps you have a shared filesystem so this is easy. Or use FTP. Or even Dropbox on each server. This depends on your setup and security requirements.
2. Generate a large text set of all SQL insert commands you want to run, and send them to the server in a single query. This takes away the need for multiple connections to the server which is slow, but it is not as efficient on the server side as a bulk insert.